# ¿Por que cuando en Android studio se ve bien, pero cuando pongo a ejecutar el emulador en Android estudio el texto no se ve?

Tags: java, app, diseño

Mi problema es que al momento de ejecutar mi emulador no se ve el texto que puse , solo se ve la imagen

[image: Esta es una imagen de mi proyecto]

Comment: Hola @BlancaVictoria, pon el código de los controles a ver como están configurados

Comment: Oki ahora lo pondré los códigos